# Speed up AJAX loading on manage display page when moving fields among regions

Tags: 7, entities, ajax, performance, display-suite

When I'm switching my fields into different regions, it takes at least 20 seconds to make it change. I'm not able to change any other field while I wait. The only work around to this was to disable javascript which let me change the regions without the ajax load and then click the save button.

What other methods can one disable this ajax loading during region changes?

[image]

Comment: Can you get a cache grind of the Ajax call? Pinpoint what's eating up all the time

Comment: Where can I learn how to do a cache grind of an ajax call?